# Simple Scan, duplex scan Epson WF-3620 not working

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I setup my [Epson WF-3620](https://www.epson.de/products/printers/inkjet-printers/microbusiness/workforce-wf-3620dwf) all in one printer / fax / scanner today. After installing the necessary drivers via Ubuntu repositories (`sudo apt install epson-inkjet-printer-escpr`) and Epsons website (`iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb`) I was able to print and scan just fine.

One thing that does not work though is the duplex-scan function which works perfectly fine when used directly on the printer itself, as well when used in a Windows 10 KVM machine.

The printer is connected to my home network via LAN.

In Simple Scan's settings I set it to scan front- and backside.

When starting a with <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> it scans the front-side just fine but it does not take the paper back in to flip it and scan the backsite.

How can I get my Epson conviced to use the duplex-scan feature?

My old printer / scanner had a checkbox in the printer menu where I could set "Duplex installed" which then worked just fine.

System:

> Ubuntu 16.04 64bit (latest updates 20160605)
>
> Kernel 4.4.0-22